# How can you run a mysqli query with CodeIgniter?

Tags: sql, codeigniter, mysqli

Does anyone have a clue how to run a mysqli query with CI. I did change the db driver in the config file, but I'm still unable to use multiple queries like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE 1;
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS c;"
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Anyone has any clue how to do this using only CI, no additional libraries, because theoretically CI supports mysqli.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this moment, even if CI supports mysqli, multiple queries are not supported as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use CI's Active Records at this time, but you can use mysqli functions with the connection / mysqli instance that CI created. Set your CodeIgniter database driver to mysqli, then call mysqli functions like
    mysqli_multi_query($this->db->conn_id...

Comment: It is a good idea to provide complete example when you are posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need for additional libraries in CI if you want to change mysql to mysqli just go to  the    config->database.php and change to `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';` to `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';`