# PREPARE STMT query from PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, prepared-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you run a mysqli query with CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059168/how-can-you-run-a-mysqli-query-with-codeigniter)

I've a mysql query that I am trying to run from php.But it is giving me a sql syntax error in codeigniter.When I copy paste the same query and run it in `mysql workbench` by replacing the `@uid` and `@rangee` with correct values, it works fine.

Here's the query :

```
$this->db->query("
            SET @uid    = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($conid,$userid).";
            SET @rangee = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($conid,$attempt)." * 50;

            PREPARE STMT FROM 
            '
            UPDATE     
                notificationrecievers 
                SET notificationrecievers.status=1 
                WHERE notificationrecievers.status=0 and notificationrecievers.recieverid=? and 

                notificationrecievers.notificationid <=
                (
                     SELECT MAX(notid) FROM
                     (
                      SELECT n.notid FROM user u,notifications n,notificationrecievers nr WHERE
                      nr.recieverid=? AND u.userid=n.senderid AND nr.notificationid=n.notid ORDER BY n.notid DESC
                      LIMIT 50 OFFSET ?
                     )e
                )   

               AND

                notificationrecievers.notificationid >=
                (
                     SELECT min(notid) FROM
                     (
                      SELECT n.notid FROM user u,notifications n,notificationrecievers nr WHERE
                      nr.recieverid=? AND u.userid=n.senderid AND nr.notificationid=n.notid ORDER BY n.notid DESC
                      LIMIT 50 OFFSET ?
                     )g
                );';
            EXECUTE STMT USING @uid,@uid,@rangee,@uid,@rangee;");
```

Why it is giving me the error ?

Comment: Well, what error is it giving you?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `query()` method is not intended to perform multiple queries.
Next, your code allows injection through $userid variable.

Better move from these raw prepared statements to binary prepared statements, as it's explained in the manual

Answer (score 0):

It's totally impossible to tell from your code what kind of object $this->db is. If it is mysqli that is used for the escaping the query() function does not support multiple statements.

Furthermore, when you use prepared statement from PHP you should use the PHP wrapper for the prepared statement as in `mysqli::prepare()`

Comment: I am using `mysqli` in `codeigniter`. I've mentioned codeigniter in the tags in which $this->db is used to make calls to the database.